Unable to run shopify theme dev command due to Ruby and Bundler issues on Windows 11
I am trying to set up a Shopify theme development environment on my Windows 11 machine
I am trying to set up a Shopify theme development environment on my Windows 11 machine. However, I am encountering several issues related to Ruby and Bundler versions. Here's a detailed breakdown of the steps I have taken and the errors I am facing:

Initial Setup:

Installed the Shopify CLI.

Attempted to run shopify theme dev command, which resulted in Ruby errors.



Error Details:

When running shopify theme dev, I get the following error:
vbnet

Copy code
ruby: invalid option -G (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)



Bundler Issues:

Attempted to resolve the issue by updating Bundler and Ruby.

Uninstalled and reinstalled various versions of Bundler. However, running bundle -v still shows Bundler version 2.5.11 despite uninstalling it.

Running gem uninstall bundler -v '2.5.11' results in the message: Gem 'bundler' is not installed.



MSYS2 Installation:

Installed MSYS2 and the MINGW development toolchain, but encountered permission errors during installation:
vbnet

Copy code
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database) error: could not lock database: Permission denied



System Specifications:

Checked that my system is 64-bit by going to System > About in Windows settings.



What I Have Tried:

Reinstalling Ruby and Bundler multiple times.

Uninstalling Bundler using various commands.

Ensuring my system has the necessary tools by installing MSYS2 and MINGW.

Running commands with administrative privileges.


Environment Details:

Operating System: Windows 11

Ruby Version: 3.3.0

Bundler Version: 2.5.11 (issue persists despite attempts to uninstall)

Shopify CLI Version: [insert version]


Specific Questions:

How can I resolve the ruby: invalid option -G error when running shopify theme dev?

Why does Bundler version 2.5.11 persist even after uninstalling it?

How can I successfully set up the Shopify theme development environment on Windows 11?



Please don't just copy-paste your question from ChatGPT. Please see our policy on generative AI usage, and ensure that you've copied your example code directly from code that you've confirmed causes the issue, not through an AI language model, as they tend to change things unpredictably, which may result in people being unable to help you. This also applies to what you've tried to solve it. Please also ensure you're asking one clear, specific question, and that you've formatted your post properly.
